# A possible disagreement with an edit

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I added an answer to my own question [about a lomo camera](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/34446/diana-f-35mm-back-cant-engage-winder-to-knob-reliably) because, well, I learned the answer. Also because someone else posted a 'I have this question, too' (non)-answer, so I thought it would be doing the universe a service to post the answer.

Someone edited my answer into an edit on my question.

Since my answer is an answer ("lomo made a mistake"), why not keep it as such? I could see editing it to say that more clearly instead of narrating my resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always edit your own question to undo the change, though it's kind of a fine line here.

Comment: I only just noticed that the editor was not a mod deleting my answer but just someone who added the content to the question. Perhaps they also flagged the answer for the mods. I'll leave it in the lap of the mods.

Comment: @bmargulies - It's not flagged, nor are there close votes, that I've seen. High rep users can see these, though we can't do all of the actions moderators can. At any rate, there's no specific harm in the change, so it's up to you.

Comment: sure enough. I'll leave it. It puts all the information in one place, and there's no harm in having it there as well as in the answer.

Comment: FWIW, I do think that there is some harm, although I wouldn't rate it catastrophic. See the question I linked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

I saw some flags on the "Me too!" answer, but not on your own. I guess it is kind of a fine line, however, it does actually answer the question, so I would say it is ok to actually post it as an answer.

Adding it as an edit is ok, but one thing I will say is that if the edit is answering the question, rather than clearing up or enhancing the question, then it really probably does belong as an answer. In your case, it is more of the latter rather than the former. Just make sure you mark it as the accepted answer (unless a better one comes along in the near future) to call it out for other potential readers.

One other thing. It really is probably best practice to ask the manufacturer first, rather than post such a question first, then ask the manufacturer. Of all the people in the world, the manufacturer's customer support staff should be best able to answer your questions. If they cannot, then you can at least alert them to the problem, allowing them to answer future customer questions. If you encounter a problem, and it is resolved by the manufacturer, you can always come here after the fact and post a question, then answer it directly, for the benefit of the community at large. It may also be helpful to include a phone number or email to the appropriate contact person at the manufacturer if a replacement part or some such is required to resolve an issue like the one you had with your lomo.

Answer (score 0):

I did the edit.  Your answer is fine.  I just thought it would be helpful, since you have a definitive answer, to add it to the original question.  It seemed like a good thing to do at the time, but now that you bring it up I'm not sure if it's necessary or not.  If you want to roll it back that's perfectly fine with me.

Comment: Please don't put answers in the question. If they're definitive, the little check mark will say so. More on this here, including rationale: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/should-edits-which-add-the-accepted-answer-to-the-question-be-reverted